# SoundManager2 has irregular latency

Tags: javascript, audio, latency, soundmanager2

I'm playing some notes at regular intervals. Each one is delayed by a random number of milliseconds, creating a jarring irregular effect. How do I fix it?

*Note: I'm OK with some latency, just as long as it's consistent.*

Answers of the type "implement your own small SoundManager2 replacement, optimized for timing-sensitive playback" are OK, if you know how to do that :) but I'm trying to avoid rewriting my whole app in Flash for now.

For an example of app with zero audible latency see the flash-based [ToneMatrix](http://lab.andre-michelle.com/tonematrix).

**Testcase
([see it here live](http://branimir-monov.hit.bg/musiclife/debug.html) or [get it in an zip](http://branimir-monov.hit.bg/musiclife/testcase.zip)):**

```
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/script/soundmanager2.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
soundManager.url = '.'
soundManager.flashVersion = 9
soundManager.useHighPerformance = true
soundManager.useFastPolling = true
soundManager.autoLoad = true

function recur(func, delay) {
    window.setTimeout(function() { recur(func, delay); func(); }, delay)
}

soundManager.onload = function() {
    var sound = soundManager.createSound("test", "test.mp3")
    recur(function() { sound.play() }, 300)
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When I run your test case, the notes are played with what sounds to me like metronomic regularity.  Does that mean I've got a better browser on a fast machine with little or no other background processes?  Or that I'm insensitive to the irregularities you hear?  Could you give a little more detail on the irregularities you are encountering -- you mention a "random number of milliseconds", but I'm pretty sure I wouldn't be able to detect the difference between, say, 5 and 15 milliseconds.
To put this another way, we can't suggest a fix if we can't hear what' s broken.

Answer (score 10):

I know this isn't the answer you want to hear, but there is no way to stop this, regardless of whether you wrote your own flash library to play sound or not.

For everyone who said "it works fine for me!" try resizing or moving your browser window as the poster's demo plays out. You'll hear more than just a subtle amount of delay. This is most noticeable in Firefox and IE, but even Chrome will experience it.

What's worse, if you click and hold the mouse down on the close box for the browser window, the sound completely stops until you release your mouse (you can release it outside of the close box and not actually close the window, FYI).

What is going on here?

It turns out that when you start resizing or moving around the browser window, the browser tries to multi-task the act of changing the window properties with the act of keeping up with the javascript going on in the window. It short-changes the window when it needs to.

When you hold down the mouse over the close box in the browser window, time stops completely. This is what is happening in smaller increments when you are re-sizing or moving the window: time is standing still in the javascript world in small, sporadic chunks (or large chunks, depending on how slow your machine is).

Now, you might say "sure, resizing the browser or holding down the close button makes the browser pause, but normally this wouldn't happen". Unfortunately you would be wrong.

It happens all the time, actually. I've run tests and it turns out that even by leaving the browser window completely still, not touching the mouse, and not touching the keyboard, backgrounds processes on the computer can still cause "hiccups", which means that for brief periods (perhaps as small as a few milliseconds) time is "standing still" in the browser, at completely random intervals outside of your control.

What do I mean by "standing still"? Let's say you have a setInterval() call (this applies to setTimeout also) running every 33 milliseconds (about 30 frames per second). Now, you would expect that after every 33 "real world" milliseconds your function would get called. And most of the time, this is true.

But when "hiccups" start happening, your setInterval call might happen in 43 milliseconds. What happened during the 10 ms? Nothing. Time stood still. Nothing on the browser was being updated. If you had sound playing, it will continue playing, but no NEW sound calls would start playing, because no javascript is being executed at all. If you had 5 setInterval() functions running, they would have all been paused for 10ms at some point.

The only way to tell that "time stood still" is to poll real-world time in your setInterval function callbacks. You'll be able to see that the browser tries to keep up most of the time, but that when you start resizing the window or doing something stressfull, the intervals will be longer than usual, but that all of your code will remain synched up (I'm making games using this technique, so you will see that all your game updates happen in synch, but just get slightly stuttered).

Usually, I should point out, these stutters are completely unnoticeable, and unless you write a function to log real-world time during setInterval times (as I have done in my own testing) you wouldn't even know about it. But it becomes a problem if you try to create some type of repetitive sound (like the beeping in the background of Asteriods) using repetitive play() calls.

My suggestion? If you have a sound that you know will loop, give it a long duration, maybe 10 seconds, and you'll be less likely to notice the hiccups (now, the graphics on the screen could still hiccup, but you're screwed there).

If you are writing a game and having the main character fire off a machine gun, don't do 10 rapid-succession calls to playSound('singleShot'), do one call to playSound('machineGunFire10Rounds'), or something along those lines.

You'll have to do some trickery to get around it, but in most cases you'll be alright.

It seems that Flash applets run in a process that is somehow less affected this whole "time freezing" thing going on in the regular browser/javascript environment, but I can still get it to happen, even on your link to the ToneMatrix example, by resizing or moving the browser window.

But Flash still seems much better than javascript. When I leave the browser alone I'd be willing to bet that Flash is not freezing for any amount of time and that intervals are always running on time.

tl;dr:

- you're screwed in what you're hoping to achieve
- try to deal with it using some workarounds
- re-write your project in pure flash (no javascript)
- wait for browsers to get better (Firefox 4 is getting a new javascript engine called [JaegerMonkey](https://wiki.mozilla.org/JaegerMonkey) which will be interesting to watch)
- how do I know all this? I've done a lot of testing & logging with javascript, setInterval, and soundManager/html5 audio calls

Answer (score 1):

In my comment to your question I mentioned that I don't hear the irregularity when I play your sample.  That means I'm either "rhythm deaf", or that there may be something in your setup that interferes with good realtime performance.  You don't mention any details of your environment, but you may have other processes running on your computer that are sucking up CPU cycles, or an older version of Flash that may not do a good job of handling sound latencies.  I myself am using a recent version of Flash (10.something), whereas your parameters call for Flash 9.  But maybe I should assume that if you're smart enough to be using SoundManager2 and StackOverflow that you would have eliminated these problems.

So here are some troubleshooting possibilities and comments that come to mind:

1) the SoundManager site has a number of demos, including [JS-DOM "painting" + Sound, V2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/animation-2b/).  Are you hearing irregular latencies and delays there?  If not, maybe you can compare what they're doing there against what you're doing.  If you are, then maybe look at your machine environment.  When I run that demo, it is very responsive.  (**EDIT:** Looking at it more closely, however, you can watch how the size of the brush stamps varies during a stroke.  Since it varies with the time interval between mouse events (assuming you are keeping a constant mouse speed), you can visually see any irregularities in the pattern of mouse events.  I can see occasional variation in stamp sizes, which does indicate that mouse events are not coming in at regular times.  Which brings us to Javascript events.)

2) Javascript `setTimeout()` and `setInterval()` are not very reliable when it comes to timing. Mostly they will come back in some ballpark of the interval you have requested, but there can be large variations, usually delays, that make them unreliable.  I've found that the same is true when using ActionScript inside Flash.  You might want to print out the times that your sound.play() call is being made to see whether the irregularities are due to the irregularities in `setTimeout/setInterval()`.  If that's the case, you could try shortening the interval, and then polling the system time to get much closer to the 300ms interval that you want.  You can poll system time using `new Date().getTime()`, and this seems to have ms accuracy.  Polling is of course a hideous hack that sucks up cycles when they could be used for something else, and I don't recommend it in general, but you may try it to see whether it helps.  **EDIT:** Here's [a writeup by John Resig on the handling of input and timer events in js](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/).

3) When flash plays sounds, there is usually a latency involved, just so that the player can "build up a head of steam" and make sure there's enough stuff in the buffer to be played before the next buffer request is filled.  There's a trade off between this latency and the reliability of uninterrupted playback.  This might be a limitation you can't do anything about, short of "implement[ing] your own small SoundManager2 replacement", which I know you don't want to do.

Hope this helps. I recently wrote an AS3 sound experiment which exposed me to some of the basics, and will be watching this space to see what other suggestions people come up with.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the javascript interval, which can not be guaranteed to fire at an exact time.  I am sure that the internal Flash timing is far more reliable.

But this might help, fire recur AFTER you have triggered playing the sound.

```
window.setTimeout(function() { func(); recur(func, delay); }, delay);
```

Comment: Thanks. The change you suggested didn't help. Also, I just realized my 'recur' function already exists in javascript, it's called window.setInterval (but this doesn't solve the problem either).

Answer (score 0):

As explained in another answer, there's no way you can avoid this. But...

I've [done some experiments](http://img.actibva.com/pulso2/#0) to mitigate this issues, and in the end I resorted to using:

- [lowLag: responsive html5 audio](http://lowlag.alienbill.com/), which uses SoundManager2 **for some cases** where it's the fastest option available.
- [GSAP JS – Professional-Grade JavaScript Animation](http://www.greensock.com/gsap-js/), in order to do the animation of properties and syncing of the audio (you probably don't care about this :P)

Take a peek at the source on the [prototype](http://demos.ditman.net/pulso) of the demo, and (if possible) give lowLag a shot. It worked nicely for me.

Good luck!